# 5 Led 12v battery level indicator

Tags: led, 12v

I've seen some simple 10 led level indicators such as [this](http://www.circuitstoday.com/12v-battery-level-indicator-circuit-led-bargraph) Due to space I cannot use 10 leds, how can I reuse this circuit or another for a 5 led indicator?

Comment: Remove 5 LEDs ?

Comment: Use only the first 5 LEDs

Comment: Use only odd numbered LEDs (D1, D3, etc) and omit the others.

Comment: Just removing the last 5, or every other, is not enough, as you will get blank spots in dot mode. Bar mode though...

Comment: @SteveG see 2 and 3 in my answer. Good idea.

Comment: @Passerby oops, sorry. I hadn't read your answer when I wrote my comment.

Comment: @SteveG no, I edited that in, in response to your comment. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few methods:

1. Use only 5 leds, and [scale the input signal to pin 6 and pin 5 to compensate.](http://tronixstuff.com/2013/09/14/tutorial-lm3914-dotbar-display-driver-ic/) Make the input signal at its highest, compared to the reference, only light the 5th led. LED 6-10 can be left unconnected.

   Update: Actually, your link already explains how to do it:

   > With little modification the circuit can be used to monitor other voltage ranges. For this just remove the resistor R3 and connect the upper level voltage to the input. Now adjust the POT R2 until LED 10 glows (in dot mode). Remove the upper voltage level and connect the lower level to the input. Now connect a high value POT (say 500K) in the place of R3 and adjust it until LED1 alone glows. Now remove the POT, measure the current resistance across it and connect a resistor of the same value in the place of R3. The level monitor is ready.

   In this case, do the same, except make LED 5 light up instead of LED 10 in the first step.
2. As @SteveG wisely pointed out, In bar mode, simply connect every other LED. It's resolution will drop by half, but it should be somewhat accurate. Leave the empty led pins unconnected. Won't work for dot mode as then you may get dark spots, times where no led is on.
3. Like 2, but better. In dot or bar mode, connect the cathode of every led to two pins. This has the nice bonus of making the led be twice as bright for every half step in bar mode. Keep the current limit in mind to prevent the leds from being overdriven.
   [image: schematic]
4. ***Use a different IC. The KA2284, LB1403, NTE1561, BA6124, AN6884 , etc are all 5 pin VU meters.*** The keywords to search for are `vu meter` or `5 dot led driver`
5. Make your own LM3914 with a couple of comparators or op amps.
   [image]
6. Make an analog meter with some transistors.
   [image]
7. Use a microcontroller and do it all in code.

[Here is an example project of a 9V battery tester](http://www.paulinthelab.com/2013/02/self-powered-9-volt-bar-led-battery.html) doing a combination of 1, 2 and 3. A 9V battery tester, has Out1-2 unconnected, Out3-5 to 1 led, and Out 9-10 on the last led.

---

The LM391x are simple comparators with a reference voltage to compare to. Nothing highly complex.

[image]